# How to deploy multiple functions using gcloud command line?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I want to deploy multiple cloud functions. Here is my `index.js`:

```js
const { batchMultipleMessage } = require('./gcf-1');
const { batchMultipleMessage2 } = require('./gcf-2');

module.exports = {
  batchMultipleMessage,
  batchMultipleMessage2
};
```

How can I use `gcloud beta functions deploy xxx` to deploy these two functions at one time.

Comment: Did you try to just use deploy without any arguments like with Firebase.  In Firebase if you use firebase deploy it deploy every function it founds in index.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

For now, I write a `deploy.sh` to deploy these two cloud functions at one time.

```sh
TOPIC=batch-multiple-messages
FUNCTION_NAME_1=batchMultipleMessage
FUNCTION_NAME_2=batchMultipleMessage2

echo "start to deploy cloud functions\n"
gcloud beta functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME_1} --trigger-resource ${TOPIC} --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish
gcloud beta functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME_2} --trigger-resource ${TOPIC} --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish
```

It works, but if `gcloud` command line support deploy multiple cloud functions, that will be best way.

**Option 2:**

https://serverless.com/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a better/cleaner/parallel solution, this is what I do:

```sh
# deploy.sh

# store deployment command into a string with character % where function name should be
deploy="gcloud functions deploy % --trigger-http"

# find all functions in index.js (looking at exports.<function_name>) using sed
# then pipe the function names to xargs
# then instruct that % should be replaced by each function name
# then open 20 processes where each one runs one deployment command
sed -n 's/exports\.\([a-zA-Z0-9\-_#]*\).*/\1/p' index.js | xargs -I % -P 20 sh -c "$deploy;"
```

You can also change the number of processes passed on the `-P` flag. I chose 20 arbitrarily.

This was super easy and saves a lot of time. Hopefully it will help someone!

Comment: Thanks for the script, it works well! However, I removed `--trigger-http` from the generated command line as you might have other types of functions (I had firestore triggers, so it was invalid).