# How to deploy all functions in single command using GCLOUD

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am aware of this `gcloud functions deploy hello --entry-point helloworld --runtime python37 --trigger-http` which would deploy only the `hello` function.

But I have multiple functions in my project

Is there a single command like firebase to deploy all functions like `firebase deploy --only functions -P default`

Answer (score 2):

Right now it is not possible to deploy multiple functions with a single command. There is already an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/77998087) requesting the same, but it is quite old.

Besides tracking the previous issue you could also fill a new [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=802601) requesting this feature.

However, I've found 2 related questions in SO with similar issues, in which the solution was to create a small script to perform this:

- [First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52732728/8905352) is a `.sh` script
- [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54238335/8905352) is a `.py` script

Hope this helps you!

Comment: 3rd: use [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/how-to)