# How to generate `gcloud functions deploy` command from existing gcloud functions?

Tags: gcloud

I already have a couple of functions deployed through google console. Now, I want them to deploy through command line. Is there any way to generate the corresponding `gcloud functions deploy` command(with as many argument prefilled as possible) for the existing functions.

I'm asking this because [`gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy) supports gazillion arguments, which would be pain to figure out manually..

Comment: Can you go through this StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976670/how-to-deploy-all-functions-in-single-command-using-gcloud) once. There are some workarounds which might help you.

Comment: thanks, their problems are different though.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question and I think this would be useful functionality.

There isn't a solution for this today (although see [Declarative Export](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/google-cloud-cli-declarative-export-preview) for an analog using Terraform).

`gcloud functions deploy` is lossy; for example, if you deployed from a local file-system using [`--source`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/functions/deploy#--source), I think this is irrecoverably lost.

That said, you can `describe` deployments as-is perfectly.

For example:

```sh
gcloud functions describe ${NAME} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

You could use the output from this command as a template for generating the `gcloud functions deploy` command.

> **NOTE** If this weren't so service-specific I'd be interested to build a prototype solution.

Comment: Looks like your first link is not correct. Thanks. Yeah, I ended up describing the function and using that to create the final command.

Comment: Corrected the link, thanks.